# how to To set your Squid server to listen on TCP port 8888

Tags: server, squid

how to To set your Squid server to listen on TCP port 8888 instead of the default TCP port 3128, change the http_port directive as such:

```
http_port 8888
```

When I write `http_port 8888` i get command error.

Comment: Please post the exact error message

Answer (score 1):

You can read the detailed documentation regarding installation/configuration of [Squid](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/squid.html).

*Prior to editing the configuration file, you should make a copy of the original file and protect it from writing so you will have the original settings as a reference to re-use as necessary.*

```
sudo cp /etc/squid/squid.conf /etc/squid/squid.conf.original
sudo chmod a-w /etc/squid/squid.conf.original
```

You should now edit (ex. `sudo nano /etc/squid/squid.conf`) the file `/etc/squid/squid.conf` and change the http_port directive to `http_port 8888`

Comment: i installed gedit by sudo apt-get install gedit 
but after i wrote sudo gedit /etc/squid3/squid.conf 
i got cannot open display run gedit --help
thxs in advance

Comment: @abedalmawlaitani You could try nano. I have update my answer.